# Why do we use flatten? How is it different from flatMap?

Tags: scala, flatmap

In scala, why do we use `flatten`? How is it different from `flatMap`?
Examples which involve Futures would be very useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between flatten and flatMap(identity)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005148/is-there-any-difference-between-flatten-and-flatmapidentity)

Comment: Or maybe possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028362/flatten-and-flatmap-in-scala

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215518/map-flatten-and-flatmap-not-equivalent

Comment: Why "possible duplicate"? The questions are related but I would not consider them duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

`flatten` does not involve the "map" part of `flatMap`. Think of it as just flattening nested structures. An `Option[Option[Int]]` becomes just an `Option[Int]` or a `List[List[Int]]` becomes a `List[Int]` (by concatenating the elements of the individual lists).

On the contrary, mapping changes the elements contained in the structures. So

```
Some(4).map(_ + 1) // evaluates to Some(5)
```

Sometimes the function passed to `map` returns an instance of the underlying structure itself. Say you have an optional id and if it is set you want to look it up in a database not knowing if a record is present, thus your function also returns an `Option`:

```
val optionalId: Option[String] = ???
def getRecord(id: String): Option[Record] = ???

val naiveResult: Option[Option[Record]] = optionalId.map(getRecord)
```

This is usually not what you want. In essence you have an `Option[Record]` and the extra nesting is not needed. So you would call `flatten` right after the `map`:

```
optionalId.map(getRecord).flatten // evaluates to an Option[Record]
```

Now `flatMap` is essentially the combination of both in one method:

```
optionalId.flatMap(getRecord) // also yields an Option[Record]
```

The application of `flatMap` is not limited to collections but much more general. Another example where it comes in handy is futures. Let's say we don't have an optional id but a Future[String] that represents a computation that will eventually yield the id. We also have a method that gives us a `Future[Record]` for an id. We can now obtain a `Future[Record]` from the `Future[String]` like this:

```
val idFuture: Future[String] = ???
def getRecord(id: String): Future[Record] = ???

val recordFuture: Future[Record] = idFuture.flatMap(getRecord)
```